# refreshing page until new data added to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, setinterval

I want to refresh a PHP page every few second with SetInterval(); and it stop refreshing the page if a data added to database. so, when it refreshing my PHP page, it always checking is there a new data added to the database or not..

I'm trying to use this kind of logic but its not working...

```
$query = mysql_num_rows(SELECT id_example FROM table_example);
$a = count($query);
$b = $a+1;

IF($a==$b)
{
Stop_refreshing_the_page;
}
else
{
Refresh_with_setInterval();
}
```

is there anyone can suggest me better logic/algorithm/code example to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which part is not working?

Also, setInterval is probably not what you want if you are refreshing the entire page each time -- seems like a simple setTimeout and reload would do the trick, then simply not print that when you have db results.

Edited for OP

I assume this is not valid PHP, but you should get the idea.

```
$previous_count = $_GET['previous_count'];
$query = mysql_num_rows(SELECT id_example FROM table_example);
$result_count = count($query);

if ($previous_count == $result_count)
{
    // this should render some javascript on the page including $result_count
}
```

The resulting javascript would be something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.setTimeout( function(){
        window.location = window.location.pathname + "?previous_count=<?php echo $previous_count; ?>";
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: if there is new data on the database, the value of $a will be always updated, and $a is never gonna be having same value with $b. so the reloading process won't stop...

Comment: You could send the old value of a as a GET parameter which the PHP page can check before deciding to render another setTimeout.

Comment: I think that is a good idea, but can you write the logic you just tell me like what I write at my question above, so it makes me easier to understand your idea...